# Como Mostrar una estructura Json en Android:

Tags: java, android

Formato respuesta Json

```
{
"status": "success",
"message": {
    "affenpinscher": [],
    "african": [],
    "airedale": [],
    "akita": [],
    "appenzeller": [],
    "basenji": [],
    "beagle": [],
    "bluetick": [],
    "borzoi": [],
    "bouvier": [],
    "boxer": [],
    "brabancon": [],
    "briard": [],
    "bulldog": [
        "boston",
        "french"
    ],
    "bullterrier": [
        "staffordshire"
    ],
    "cairn": [],
    "chihuahua": [],
    "chow": [],
    "clumber": [],
    "collie": [
        "border"
    ],
    "coonhound": [],
    "corgi": [
        "cardigan"
    ],
    "dachshund": [],
    "dane": [
        "great"
    ],
    "deerhound": [
        "scottish"
    ],
    "dhole": [],
    "dingo": [],
    "doberman": [],
    "elkhound": [
        "norwegian"
    ],
    "entlebucher": [],
    "eskimo": [],
    "germanshepherd": [],
    "greyhound": [
        "italian"
    ],
    "groenendael": [],
    "hound": [
        "Ibizan",
        "afghan",
        "basset",
        "blood",
        "english",
        "walker"
    ],
    "husky": [],
    "keeshond": [],
    "kelpie": [],
    "komondor": [],
    "kuvasz": [],
    "labrador": [],
    "leonberg": [],
    "lhasa": [],
    "malamute": [],
    "malinois": [],
    "maltese": [],
    "mastiff": [
        "bull",
        "tibetan"
    ],
    "mexicanhairless": [],
    "mountain": [
        "bernese",
        "swiss"
    ],
    "newfoundland": [],
    "otterhound": [],
    "papillon": [],
    "pekinese": [],
    "pembroke": [],
    "pinscher": [
        "miniature"
    ],
    "pointer": [
        "german"
    ],
    "pomeranian": [],
    "poodle": [
        "miniature",
        "standard",
        "toy"
    ],
    "pug": [],
    "pyrenees": [],
    "redbone": [],
    "retriever": [
        "chesapeake",
        "curly",
        "flatcoated",
        "golden"
    ],
    "ridgeback": [
        "rhodesian"
    ],
    "rottweiler": [],
    "saluki": [],
    "samoyed": [],
    "schipperke": [],
    "schnauzer": [
        "giant",
        "miniature"
    ],
    "setter": [
        "english",
        "gordon",
        "irish"
    ],
    "sheepdog": [
        "english",
        "shetland"
    ],
    "shiba": [],
    "shihtzu": [],
    "spaniel": [
        "blenheim",
        "brittany",
        "cocker",
        "irish",
        "japanese",
        "sussex",
        "welsh"
    ],
    "springer": [
        "english"
    ],
    "stbernard": [],
    "terrier": [
        "american",
        "australian",
        "bedlington",
        "border",
        "dandie",
        "fox",
        "irish",
        "kerryblue",
        "lakeland",
        "norfolk",
        "norwich",
        "patterdale",
        "scottish",
        "sealyham",
        "silky",
        "tibetan",
        "toy",
        "westhighland",
        "wheaten",
        "yorkshire"
    ],
    "vizsla": [],
    "weimaraner": [],
    "whippet": [],
    "wolfhound": [
        "irish"
    ]
}
```

Estoy accediendo de la siguiente manera el modelo:

```
    public static class DogSumary {
    public String status;
    public ArrayList<String> message;
}
```

La clase:

```
     @Override
     public void onRequestResponse(Object response, int taskId) {

    DogModel.DogSumary datos = (DogModel.DogSumary) response;

    Log.i(getClass().getName(), "LIST DOG " + datos.message);

    for (int i = 0; i < datos.message.size(); i++){

    Log.i(getClass().getName(), "Lista de razas"+datos.message.get(i));

         }


    loader.dismiss();
    }
```

Surgue el siguiente error

```
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 13 path $.message
```

Comment: Si es un array de `razas`, tendrías que leer las sub-razas iterando sobre el array `razas` en cada ocurrencia. Es decir, en vez de tratar `razas` como un string, tendrías que tratarlo como un `array`.

Comment: Que libreria estas utilizando para deserializar el json a un objeto?

Comment: @Einer Hola, Gson

Comment: Cuando obtienes la respuesta del server, la propiedad `message` del objeto `DogSumary` trae resultados?

Comment: @Einer Esta surgiendo lo siguien Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 13 path $.message

Answer (score 0):

No se como funciona GSON internamente por lo que la forma en como pude resolverlo fue la siguiente:

En el json, la propiedad `message` tiene la estructura de un diccionary con la llave String y el valor un array de string y no se como se representaria ese valor en GSON.

Por lo que puedes intentar convertir el string del json al objeto DogSumary con JSONObject.

Primero debes de agregarle otra entidad donde representara la raza de los perros y sus reprectivos nombres:

```
public static class DogSumary {
        public String status;
        public ArrayList<DogCategory> message;
    }

public static class DogCategory
{
       public String raceName;
       public String[] dogs;
}
```

Ahora solo tendrias que por cada raza en la propiedad `message`, buscar los nombres de los perros.

```
 public DogSumary parseJSON(String json)
 {


     try {

        JSONObject json = new JSONObject(json);
        JSONObject messageJson = json.getJSONObject("message");

        DogSumary dogSumary = new DogSumary();
        dogSumary.message = new ArrayList<>();


        Iterator it = messageJson.keys(); 
        while(it.hasNext())           
        {
            // por cada raza de perro, buscamos los nombres de los mismos
            String raceName = it.next().toString();
            DogCategory category = new DogCategory();
            category.raceName = raceName;

            // aqui se buscan los valores de cada raza:  "affenpinscher": [], "african": []...
            JSONArray dogsArray = messageJson.getJSONArray(raceName.toString());

            category.dogs = new String[dogsArray.length()];
            for(int i = 0; i < dogsArray.length();i++)
            {
                category.dogs[i] = dogsArray.getString(i);
            }      
        }

        return dogSumary;
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(JavaApplication1.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (JSONException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(JavaApplication1.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

    return null;
}
```

Entonces en el metodo que recibe la respuesta solo tendrias que hacer esto:

```
 JsonObjectRequest jsonRequet = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, (String) null,
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                public void onResponse(JSONObject result) {

                     onPostExecute();
                     DogSumary sumary = parseJSON(result.toString());
                     listener.onRequestResponse(sumary, id);

                     //...
```